# How to capture an input device and prevent it's default behavior

Tags: c, node.js, linux, windows, io

I have an RFID tag reader. But it works like a HID device (like a keyboard). It sends keystrokes to the computer when a tag is scanned. When I open notepad and scan a tag - it types the ID one digit at a time. Is there a way to create a program to listen to this device (or this port) and capture (intercept) all input. So that the keystrokes wouldn't appear on my system but I could assign my own events when the device sends and input. I don't want it to show up on Notepad.

I realize that the implementation can differ depending on the OS and programming language used. Ideally, I would like to make this work on both Windows and Linux. I would prefer to use something like Node.js but I suppose C could also be good.

I would appreciate any hints or pointing me in the right direction.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open the raw input device for reading (basically `ioctl` with parameter `EVIOCGRAB` for Linux and `RegisterRawInputDevices()` for Windows as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668872/need-to-intercept-hid-keyboard-events-and-then-block-them) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209267/capture-hid-keyboard-event)). However, the mechanisms are quite [different for Windows and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463652/determine-input-from-different-devices), so you will end up implementing all the low-level logic twice.

It should also be possible to read the input data stream from the standard input just like you would read an input from the keyboard (e.g. `scanf()` or `fgets()` in C) with some logic that recognizes when a data set (= tag ID) is complete - the reader device might for example terminate an input with a newline `'\n'` or null character `'\0'`.

You should probably do this in a separate thread and have some kind of producer-consumer mechanism or event model for communication with your main application.

Comment: yes I am able to read from the USB port. But how do I prevent it from sending HID keystrokes to the OS? I would like to intercept them.

Comment: I think this is explained in the linked questions: `ioctl` with parameter `EVIOCGRAB` for Linux and `RegisterRawInputDevices()` for Windows should give you exclusive access. Edited my answer, too.

Comment: Thank you, Gerd! I was search all day for this! That seems to be what I was looking for!

Comment: Also found a Node.js package that uses ````ioctl```` and ````EVIOCGRAB```` here https://github.com/pfirpfel/node-exclusive-keyboard

Comment: Seems like for Windows I needed to install a hook using ````SetWindowsHookEx````